# Cannot show JTable in JFrame

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, jframe

I am trying to show the results of an sql query "SELECT * FROM..." in a JFrame. After a bit of digging I made the below using and some code that I found in another post here. My problem is that it does not show the Jtable in my JFrame. I am complete newbie in this (this is my first try combining sql and java for gui) so any help would be really appreciated...

CODE for frame:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Frame  extends JFrame {

    public Frame() throws HeadlessException {
        super();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Border loweredetched = null;
        Font font = new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 11);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);


        leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        //JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(GetSongs.table);


        /*JTextArea text = new JTextArea(15, 3);
        text.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        text.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        text.setForeground(Color.white);
        text.setFont(font);
        text.setEditable(false);*/

        JButton button = new JButton("Update");
        lowerPanel.add(button);

        leftPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(loweredetched, "Songs"));
        leftPanel. add( new JScrollPane( GetSongs.table ), BorderLayout.CENTER );;
        leftPanel.add(lowerPanel);


        JTextArea textR = new JTextArea(1, 3);
        textR.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        textR.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        textR.setForeground(Color.white);
        textR.setFont(font);
        textR.setEditable(false);

        rightPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(loweredetched, "ToBuy"));
        rightPanel.add(textR);


        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Frame();
        }
}
```

CODE of class to connect to db and make query:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.*;

public class GetSongs extends JFrame {

// MAKES A QUERY TAKES THE RESULT SET AND PRODUCES A JTABLE
    public static JTable table;

    public GetSongs() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/songs";
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;

        //do not use in production!!
        String dbuser = "root";
        String dbpass = "";

        ResultSet rs = null;

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); //
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, dbuser, dbpass);
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM songs JOIN purchases WHERE id = song_id and user_id =2;";
        rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

        table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    }

    public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
            throws SQLException {

        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

        // names of columns
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println(columnCount);
        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
        }

        // data of the table
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
            }
            data.add(vector);
        }

        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    }

}
```

Comment: GetSongs does not need to extend JFrame. GetSongs.table should not be static. When you add GetSongs.table to the JScrollPane in Frame (which gets added to the leftPane) it is null, therefore nothing gets added, nor can anything get updated. You are creating a new JTable each time you make a new instance of GetSongs, in of itself, not a bad thing, but it's what you're not doing within it that's an issue, it never gets displayed on the screen. I suggest you reduce the complexity of your program and work on understanding just how the JTable works

Comment: Start by having a look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use a SwingWorker.

You would retrieve all the database information in the doInBackground() method, and then you would populate your table in the done() method.

Since I can't explain it all to you, there is more information here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html